# SQL how to combine two outputs together

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

How to create one output from two SQL queries? Retrieving data from a SQL Server CE (`.SDF` file) database.

I have the 1st query

```
SELECT 
    testruns.id, testruns.stoptime, testruns.serialnumber, testruns.testcell,
    teststeps.testname, teststeps.measurement AS Test4_Measurement 
FROM
    teststeps, testruns
WHERE 
    teststeps.testrun = testruns.id
    AND stoptime > '10/05/2016 1:00 PM' 
    AND stoptime < '10/05/2016 2:00 PM'
    AND teststeps.testname = 'Test 4: Low Power Mode Current'
    AND teststeps.status = 'Pass'
```

I get the output

```
id      stoptime            serialnumber    testcell    testname                        Test4_Measurement
57898   10/5/2016 1:01 PM   16363226        2           Test 4: Low Power Mode Current  46.24566
57899   10/5/2016 1:01 PM   16363227        3           Test 4: Low Power Mode Current  44.94964
57900   10/5/2016 1:01 PM   16363228        4           Test 4: Low Power Mode Current  42.77687
```

I have the 2nd query

```
SELECT testruns.id, testruns.stoptime, testruns.serialnumber ,testruns.testcell, teststeps.testname, teststeps.measurement AS Test7_Measurement 
FROM teststeps, testruns
WHERE 
teststeps.testrun = testruns.id
AND
stoptime > '10/05/2016 1:00 PM' AND stoptime < '10/05/2016 2:00 PM'
AND
teststeps.testname = 'Test 7: Advertisements Current'
AND
teststeps.status = 'Pass'
```

I get the 2nd output

```
id      stoptime            serialnumber    testcell    testname                        Test7_Measurement
57898   10/5/2016 1:01 PM   16363226        2           Test 7: Advertisements Current  12.8
57899   10/5/2016 1:01 PM   16363227        3           Test 7: Advertisements Current  12.6
57900   10/5/2016 1:01 PM   16363228        4           Test 7: Advertisements Current  12.6
```

I need to get the output

```
id      stoptime            serialnumber    testcell    testname                        Test4_Measurement   testname                        Test7_Measurement
57898   10/5/2016 1:01 PM   16363226        2           Test 4: Low Power Mode Current  46.24566            Test 7: Advertisements Current  12.8
57899   10/5/2016 1:01 PM   16363227        3           Test 4: Low Power Mode Current  44.94964            Test 7: Advertisements Current  12.6
57900   10/5/2016 1:01 PM   16363228        4           Test 4: Low Power Mode Current  42.77687            Test 7: Advertisements Current  12.6
```

Comment: `... FROM teststeps AS t4, teststeps AS t7, testruns ...` - if You need to use the same table twice in single query, use table aliases (t4, t7 in this case).

Comment: And please use the modern ANSI joins. The join types you have are out of date

Comment: Column stoptimes data type?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT testruns.id, testruns.stoptime, testruns.serialnumber, testruns.testcell, teststeps.testname

 ,CASE WHEN teststeps.testname = 'Test 4: Advertisements Current'
 THEN teststeps.measurement 
 END AS [Test4_Measurement]

 ,CASE WHEN teststeps.testname = 'Test 7: Low Power Mode Current'
 THEN teststeps.measurement 
 END AS Test7_Measurement

FROM teststeps JOIN testruns ON teststeps.testrun = testruns.id

--ALTHOUGH I THINK YOU MEAN THIS??
--FROM teststeps JOIN testruns on teststeps.id = testruns.id

WHERE stoptime > '10/05/2016 1:00 PM'
    AND stoptime < '10/05/2016 2:00 PM'
    --AND teststeps.testname IN ('Test 7: Advertisements Current','Test 4: Advertisements Current')
    AND teststeps.STATUS = 'Pass'
```

Comment: The teststeps.testrun = testruns.id is correct.  .testrun is how it links to the other table.

This is getting close but the results I get is,

'code'57898 10/5/2016 1:01 PM 16363226 2 Test 3: Low Power Mode Raw Current  
57898 10/5/2016 1:01 PM 16363226 2 Test 4: Low Power Mode Current  
57898 10/5/2016 1:01 PM 16363226 2 Test 5: Advertisements Error Current  
57898 10/5/2016 1:01 PM 16363226 2 Test 6: Advertisements Raw Current  
57898 10/5/2016 1:01 PM 16363226 2 Test 7: Advertisements Current

//The measurement columns do not have any data.
// I am getting other tests

Comment: Sorry could not figure out how to have the comments formatted.

Comment: Lets start by commenting out

Comment: AND teststeps.testname IN ('Test 7: Advertisements Current','Test 4: Advertisements Current')

Comment: I found one issue, I copied your example and it had the Test # and name backwards.  Corrected this and I get the measurement data for test 4 & test 7 in the correct columns.

The issue is I get them listed on separate rows.

57897 10/5/2016 1:00 PM 16363225 1 Test 7: Advertisements Current  12.6
57898 10/5/2016 1:01 PM 16363226 2 Test 4: Low Power Mode Current 46.24566

Comment: Ok, Lets get the corrected code posted. Also how would you combine the two records you mention (they have no connecting key) ?

Comment: The connecting key would be the testruns.id.  Not sure how to post corrected code here in the comment and have it readable.  My goal is to have the Test 4 & Test 7 measurements on the same outputted row.

Comment: If you add your two source tables (headers with 2-3 rows), I'll give it a shot. Use the formatting tags in the code window you initially posted in to format your text.